# Shim/fake object using external application

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, microsoft-fakes, shim

i've got class as below and i need to test **RunMethod**. Problem is, that ExternalClass needs some application run on server side (app providing external dll's). My dev environment has that app but my dev environment for test hasn't. My question is, how to shim/fake that ExternalClass in UnitTests to not check if app exist (test always faild in env without that external app)? This class is not important in tests but run automatically if i execute RunMethod.

```
public class MyExampleClass : ISomeInterface
{
    private static ExternalClass = new ExternalClass(string someParam);

    public object RunMethod()
    {
        /* Actuall code hear, doesn't matter */
        /* few unimportant (from the view point of tester) operation in ExternalClass (object loggin etc.) */
        return someVar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

MsFakes generate a property named `AllInstances` to the shim class, through this property you can override the behavior of any instance method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        ShimExternalClass.AllInstances.ToString01 = () =>
        {
            return String.Empty();
        };

        Assert.IsNull(new ExternalClass().ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But, what if all methods in my **ExternalClass** are void (return nothig, just doing some log stuff) and using external assembly (for that logging opearation) which i can't provide in my test server?

Comment: @JamesTheEvangelist change the method to do nothing: `ShimExternalClass.AllInstances.Log = () => {};`

Comment: I'm just try something like this `ShimExternalClass.AllInstances.SomeMethod = (null);` and i've got still error that `The type 'some lib' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'assembly'.`

Comment: `... You must add a reference to assembly 'assembly'.` -> add the assembly to the UT project...

Comment: Sure, i did it. Now my test failed in build server cause i haven't got application (i meant about it in first post) installed there. `Test method MyTestMethod threw exception: 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MyExampleClass' threw an exception. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. - StackTrace`

Comment: If it locally works, then you have a problem in your build server settings.[Prepare to run tests in your build process.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253138%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Prepare)